# Variable substitution not working if multiple layers are provided in WMS call

Tags: geoserver, wms

I use cql expressions to make my color map entries dynamic as described here: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rastersymbolizer.html#cql-expressions

It works basically, but as soon as I add an additional layer in my WMS call (&layers=layer1,layer_raster) the parameters I pass in the URL (&env=low:10;medium:100;...) are just ignored and the default values I defined with the cql expression are applied.

Does anyone know about this issue? I am using GeoServer 2.8.0.

Comment: Thinking that semicolon is used as a separator between layer wise CQL filters if WMS request is made with a list of layers. Perhaps the same thing happens for you because the ENV variable contains semicolons. Perhaps semicolons should be escaped or the whole value of "ENV" enclosed somehow.

Comment: I tried it with one cql filter variable only, so I didn't use a semicolon here

Comment: You mean you tried something else than  (&env=low:10;medium:100;...)?, Could you add a complete request? Even better if you can get the error to appear with the GeoServer demo layers.

Comment: This is my request:
http://server:8080/geoserver/prog/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=layer_1,layer_raster&ENV=threshold1:0&styles=&bbox=8..,48..,8..,48..&width=767&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

(I anonymized the coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been answered on the geoserver-users mailing list, it's a bug in env usage inside raster symbolizer happening when multiple layers are requested:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Variable-substitution-not-working-if-multiple-layers-are-provided-in-WMS-call-td5271011.html

The env function works otherwise  fine (against one or more vector layers, or against single layer raster ones).